# How to disable video by default in React native agora uikit?

Tags: react-native, agora.io

How to disable video by default? or how to make audio call in agora ui kit for react native?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kd0YGr1iHjs

In here around 11:00 the presenter passes a property called `dualStreamMode`. Check if that works.